# Ubuntu Touch - clearing down notifications on restart

Tags: ubuntu-touch, notification

Today, I had two notifications in the morning. One for a text message and one for a Telegram message. The notification's icon at the top of the screen was highlighted as normal. Then while trying to make a call, my phone crashed and I needed to restart it. When it came back up the notifications for the two messages had gone and the notification icon (at the top of the screen) was normal.

What settings do I need to change to stop this from happening in the future? As if the phone goes down, battery goes, crashes or anything like that. I do not want a situation where I do not know about messages, emails, calls and such like as the notification has been cleared down and not by me actioning them.

Comment: It's a bug. http://pad.lv/1388189

Comment: Cheers, I did look but didn't see it. Lets hope that the fix for these bugs will come soon as when they do, the notifications will be so much better.

Comment: I have added this comment to the bug this morning - Wishlist → High & importance: Medium → High, but there has not been an update since the 26th Jan. Is there an update or eta for this?

Answer (score 0):

This has been raised as a defect and awaiting a fix under https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/1388189
Thanks to pomsky for providing the details.